# Azure: Every few hours, REST request to database takes many seconds to return response. Why?

Tags: javascript, spring, postgresql, azure, spring-boot

I have a web site whose backend is being deployes on Azure as an App Service, and it uses "Azure Database for PostgreSQL server" as its database.

I use the free Azure license.

On my frontend, I use a JS promise on my FE to access my BE.
Generally, everything works well!

But what I noticed is that every few hours (24 maybe - I'm not sure), it takes many seconds, maybe even more than 60 for the response to arrive!

What I understood so far is that I need to restart the db and then the app to have normal responses time, since I make the first request on app startup.
But it doesn't really work for me...

Is it an Azure known issue? How can I handle this?

Frontend js function:

```
function populateTeamsMenu(btnElem) {
    
    try {

        //Populate with new items:
        (async () => {
            const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + PORT + "/teams");
            var teamsArrObj = await response.json();
            console.log(teamsArrObj);
         ...
    }
```

Backend spring\jpa code:

```
private final TeamRepository teamRepository;

public List<Team> retrieveAllTeams() {

    List<Team> lst;
    lst = teamRepository.findAll();
    return lst;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you correctly disposing the connection objects in your server side code? Since everything works after a restart, i would recommend checking the code that calls your database and see if you are running out of connections in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is probably becuase I am using a free account, a consumption plan.
You can see the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan